# invalid operation exception in copying data from data grid to database table

Tags: mysql, c#-4.0, datagridview, invalidoperationexception

I am copying data from a `DataGridView` to a database table name test1, but an *invalid operation exception* is being raised. How do I fix this?

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView2.Rows)
{
    string mysqlStatement = "INSERT INTO test1(Paper, Authors, ID, GSCitations)VALUES("+row.Cells[0]+","+row.Cells[1]+","+row.Cells[2]+","+row.Cells[3]+");";
    MySqlCommand mysqlCmd = new MySqlCommand(mysqlStatement, connection);
    mysqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enclose any string values in quotes within the SQL as well as within the C# code. I'm assuming that that ID is numeric, so have not enclosed cell 2 in quotes.

```
    string mysqlStatement = "INSERT INTO test1(Paper, Authors, ID, GSCitations) VALUES ('"+row.Cells[0]+"','"+row.Cells[1]+"',"+row.Cells[2]+",'"+row.Cells[3]+"');";
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have a typo, put space before `VALUES`.

Then, based on the columns written, I think you have a `varchar` data types, which you should put their values between quotes. Somehow like this

```
    string mysqlStatement = "INSERT INTO test1(Paper, Authors, ID, GSCitations) 
    VALUES('" + row.Cells[0].Value + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value + "'," 
    + row.Cells[2].Value + ",'" + row.Cells[3].Value + "');";
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace for the exception?